# The relation between contraction and deletion in a matroid.

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, matroids, algebraic-combinatorics

Here is the relation I have seen a lot in the books, but I am not sure why it is always true:

If $T \subseteq E(M)$ then  $$M \setminus T = (M^* / T)^* \quad\quad (*)$$

I know that contraction is defined as $$M/T = (M^* \setminus T)^*$$ I tried taking the dual of this definition but I do not think that this is the correct way of thinking. I also know the following proposition:

$M \setminus T = M/T$ iff $r(T) + r(E - T) = r(M)$ but I do not know hoe can this help.

Is there a proof for why is this relation $(*)$ true?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take your definition of contraction and apply it to the matroid $M^*$ to get $M^*/T=(M^{**}\setminus T)^*$. Therefore, in your desired equation $(*)$, the right side is $(M^{**}\setminus T)^{**}$.  Since every matroid is equal to its double-dual, this reduces to $M\setminus T$, i.e., the left side of (*).